# identity operator, direct sums, and projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

> Let $W$ be finite-dimensional vector space.
>   Let $P: W\to W$ be a projection. Let $U = \text{Range}(P)$ and $V = \ker(P)$
>
> (a) show that $P$ is the identity operator on $U$.

I don't understand the problem statement

> (b) show that $W = U \oplus V$ where the decomposition is given by $w=u+v$ with $u=P(w)$ and $v = w-P(w)$

$\forall w \in W$, we can write:

\begin{align}
w &=w\\
&= P(w)-w+P(w)\\
&=u+v
\end{align}

> (c)show that if $P$ is an orthogonal projection then it is self-adjoin.

I would appreciate if you can give me hints on how to solve this problem.

Comment: For (a), you are asked to show that for all $u \in U$, $Pu = u$.
For (b), you need also to show that $u$ and $v$ are unique. (If we are talking about the direct sum of $U$ and $V$.) You could accomplish this if you could show that $0$ could be uniquely decomposed. 
For (c), if P is an orthogonal projection, you need to show that for $y \in W, x \in W$, $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$

Comment: I made a mistake. I should have stated that 0 is the only element of $U \cap V$, instead of the unique decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) you have to show, that $P|_U$ is the identity, that is for all $u \in U = \def\R{\mathrm{Range}}\R(P)$ you have $u = Pu$.

> Hint. Write $u \in U$ as $u = Pw$ for some $w \in W$ and use the projection property.

For (b) you already showed that $W = U+V$, it remains to show that the sum is direct, that is $U \cap V = \{0\}$.

> Hint. For $w \in \ker P \cap \R(P)$, we have $Pw = 0$ as $w \in \ker P$, but using (a) $P$ is the identity on $\R(P)$, so $Pw = \mathord ?$

For (c), if $P$ is orthogonal, we have $\ker P \perp \R(P)$. We want to show that $\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<Pw, w'> = \<w, Pw'>$, all $w, w' \in W$.

> Hint. Write $w = u+v$, $w' = u'+v'$ with $u,u'\in \R(P)$, $w,w' \in \ker P$. Then $Pw = u$, $Pw' = u'$, now compute $\<Pw, w'>$ and $\<w, Pw'>$ using $\<u,v'> = \<v,u'> = 0$.

Comment: is there any error in hint 3 @martini

Comment: For hint 2: Why do we need to show that the intersection of those  two sets are empty? @martini

Comment: @user235727 (1) Yes, there was an error, corrected it. (2) That's the very definition of direct sum.